# Playing YouTube on iOS 5 without leaving application

Tags: ios, ios4, youtube

My application needs to support to play YouTube video and shows the first frame as Thumbnail. Since we need to keep our application running about playing video, therefore, in iOS 4.3.5, we used a method to embed a HTML link in a WebView. It works fine to play Video with YouTube player and it would return to my application upon finished.

Unfortunately, this method does not work. Any suggestion ?

My previous method is as follows:

NSString* embedHTML = @"body {background-color: transparent;color: white;}
    ";

NSString* html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, url, frame.size.width, frame.size.height];

```
NSLog(@"HTML = %@", html);
UIWebView* videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];  
videoView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[videoView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
[_supview addSubview:videoView];  
[videoView release];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
- (void)embedYouTube:(NSString*)url frame:(CGRect)frame {
   NSString* embedHTML = @"\
    <html><head>\
    <style type=\"text/css\">\
    body {\
    background-color: transparent;\
    color: white;\
    }\
    </style>\
    </head><body style=\"margin:0px\">\
    <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
             width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
    </body></html>";

   NSString* html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, url, 
          frame.size.width, frame.size.height];
   NSLog(@"%@",html);
   if(youtube == nil) {
        youtube = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        [self.view addSubview:youtube];
   }
  [youtube loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
  [youtube setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
}
```

Comment: Sorry about that. Actually, my previous codes are exactly the same as you provided.

Comment: Can you also share your youtube link to me ? I use the same piece of work but it is not working as described. The video link that I am playing is http://www.youtube.com/user/Brandstw?blend=5＆ob=5#p/a/u/1/0jYpTIpJxlg

Comment: It is the HTML that is loaded to UIWebView. <html><head>    <style type="text/css">    body {    background-color: transparent;    color: white;    }    </style>    </head><body style="margin:0">    <embed id="yt" src="http://www.youtube.com/user/Brandstw?blend=5＆ob=5#p/a/u/1/0jYpTIpJxlg" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"     width="98" height="85"></embed>    </body></html>

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 5 or new apps use official syntax, see the link below it works very fine

http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/07/new-way-to-embed-youtube-videos.html